# SerialPort object does not receive any data under Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, serial-port, windows-xp

I have a SerialPort object to control a gsm modem connected to a virtual com port. My problem is that i do not receive any data under Windows XP. The `DataReceived` Event is not triggered nor outputs `port.ReadExisting()` any data if called periodically. But when i shut down my program and connect with putty to this port, the response of the modem is displayed.

Under Windows 7 data is received correctly.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Can you please add the settings from Putty and the settings from your application? Just for a small comparation.

Comment: Please Install the driver for the Connected device.Usually RS232 Driver

Comment: Could you post minimal code sample, which works under Win7 and doesn't work under WinXP?

Comment: @adricadar thank you for your answer. I think I have asked and did too less investigation. I compared with the Putty settings and found out that software handshake needs to be enabled (see my own answer below). But maybe this helps someone doing the same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software handshake needs to be enabled.

```
this.serialPort.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.XOnXOff;
```

I found this out by comparing the putty settings with the serial port settings in my program. So the problem was not the operating system itself, but the used flow control.